# toggle GNOME EXTENSIONS -option on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell-extension

i have installed `hide top bar` extension from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/. As the extension name mean. It will make the top bar disappear when there is a app open and hover on it, but it there is also an option that, top-bar will pop up again when the mouse reach at top-screen-edge. When i install the extensions by CLI (i use gnome-extensions-cli package), the top-bar auto disappear immediately - exactly what i want. But the `pop-up option` do not set. For clearer, it mean when mouse pointer reach the top-screen-edge, the top-bar do not re-appear. I don't know how to access - setting this extension option - which implied in the description of the extension by CLI. I've find TWEAK or dconf-editor but it not CLI. Adding more, i also open and searching in dconf-editor, there are not any key for hide-top-bar.

so, i'm ok. But is there command line for the problem? Thanks in advance